# Condition to insert text in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using `ng-options` I am populating a `select` input with data from a response. The property used to populate the `select` input can have null values. If this is the case, I need to insert replacement text `[No client reference provided]`.

```
<select data-ng-options="item.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber for item in item.renewalUIs">
    <option value="">Multiple</option>
</select>
```

I know with directives such as `ng-class` you can add conditionals to the view like so:

```
<p data-ng-class="$ctrl.variationSave ? 'txt-phase-green': 'txt-phase-red'">Variation</p>
//variationSave evaluates to true, add class txt-phase-green
```

***Question***

Is there a way to add a condition to `ng-options` similar to the `ng-class` directive in the view, to check whether there is text or not, and if not, add replacement text?

Comment: You should do this in the controller.

Comment: Access the object and add the text?

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you

Comment: Yes @PatrickMcDermott, that's the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised in above comment, I added the condition in controller to insert replacement text, like so:

```
vm.tableData = vm.transactions;

vm.tableData.forEach(function(data){
    if(data.renewalUIs.length > 1) { //not required, but for my scenario it is
        data.renewalUIs.map(function(o, i){ 
            if(o.patentUI.clientRef == '') {
                o.patentUI.clientRef = '[No Client Description Provided]'
            }

        })                  
    }
})
```